# single button with two working activity

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-activity, sms

I am developing an android sms app.

There is a single send button on my app when users click on the send button, the sms will send to desired number.

My problem is that I want to add another activity to the send button. When users click on the send button, I want his message sent along with a new page that opens, containing `thanks`.

I have created the thanks page, but I don't know how to make intent to this page along with send sms. I have tried by writing the intent code above the sms code in the `mainactivity.java` class, but it is sending sms ant not redirecting the user to the thanks page.

Comment: plz provide me onclick method

Comment: onClick code please....

Comment: whats happen if you add a callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an onclick `android:onClick="sendMessage"` on the button, then write in the "sendMessage" method (or whatever your methods name is) use this

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    //TODO write your send sms crap
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThanksPage.class); //starts new intent
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I had tried using this..but in this I got a trouble...when there is no message typed in the text box and user click on send button then the intent is working , user is taken to the thanks page without sending a message...when user type something in text box .then intent is not working only intent is working.....I want both to work in a single clik....

Comment: @user3248520 I don't understand your problem..When the textfield is blank, then it will start the new intent? but when the user has text in it, it only sends the text and doesn't start the new intent? Is this what you are saying?

Comment: @user3248520 Make sure you are starting the new intent inside the method that the message is being sent in. You can even set a timer so it doesn't start the intent right away, but takes a few seconds. Another option is to destroy the current activity, and re-instantiate it instead of just starting a new one. Try giving some examples of your code, as it is much easier seeing what you are doing wrong, than trying to guess.

Comment: Thankss tyson....I was weiting the intent method after the sms method.....I replaced it after send button now its working finee